# Contact Form Send a copy to user/sender

Tags: php, html, email

I have a website template with a contact form and sendmail.php file. What I want to do is give the sender the option to send a copy of the form to themselves.

I've tried different suggestions which I've found online but without success. 
I've managed to get the checkbox option in the html file pretty easily, but even if it's selected, the sender doesn't get a copy of the email. So my thinking is that there's something on the PHP end that I'm missing or have down incorrectly.

I tried:

```
//cc option
$headers["From"] = "$clientEmail";
$headers["To"] = "$emailTo";
$headers["Subject"] = $subject;
$headers['Cc'] = '$clientEmail';
```

but that didn't work.

Here is the HTML and PHP code:

HTML:

```
        <div class="contact-us container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="contact-form span7">
                    <p>Want to get in touch? Use the form below to send an email.</p>
                    <form method="post" action="assets/sendmail.php">
                        <label for="name" class="nameLabel">Name</label>
                          <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name...">
                        <label for="email" class="emailLabel">Email</label>
                          <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                          <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your subject...">
                        <label for="message" class="messageLabel">Message</label>
                          <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
                        <button id="button">Send</button>
                    </form>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="sendCopy" name="sendCopy" class="rsp-cB"/>
                    <label for="sendCopy">Send me a copy.</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PHP:

```
// Email address verification
if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'email@gmail.com'; 

    $clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
    $clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);

    $array = array();
    $array['nameMessage'] = '';
    $array['emailMessage'] = '';
    $array['messageMessage'] = '';

    if($clientName == '') {
        $array['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your name.';
    }
    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
    }
    if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '') {
        // Send email
    $headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }

    header('Location: thanks.php');
}?>
```

I'm a complete newbie so please suggest, in layperson terms, what is required and in which files and where.

P.S. I know there are other similar questions on here, but I've tried them as well as googling for other suggestions and I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use headers as **array** like this

```
// Cc option
$headers["From"]    = "$clientEmail";
$headers["To"]      = "$emailTo";
$headers["Subject"] = $subject;
$headers['Cc']      = "$clientEmail";
```

### Correct way is.

```
$to      = 'reciver_address@gmail.com';   // Recipient of email
$subject = 'I\'m sending a mail';         // Subject of email
$message = 'This is message';             // Body of email
$header  = 'From: address@gmail.com';     // Sender email address
$header .= "\r\n" . 'Cc: copy@gmail.com'; // Copy of email
```

Then in [`mail()`](https://php.net/mail)

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Comment: that's a suggestion I'd found online, but good to know.
The 'correct' way broke the page btw. Solved it though, thanks to Stijn Raeymaekers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this header.

```
$headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail. "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Cc: " . $clientEmail. "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is the PHP Part missing. If you use the BuildIN PHP Mail function you have to add the CC to the headers.

Not tested, but add this to your code below the first "$header" and it should send an copy to the Client:

```
 // add CC when checked in Form and attach to headers
 if ($_POST['sendCopy'] == '1') {
     $headers .= "Cc: $clientEmail" . "\r\n";
 }
```

I would recommend to have a look at some better Mail Solutions like: [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

please try this(ignore code before)

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {         

    if($_POST['sendCopy']=="1") {    

        // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
        $emailTo = 'email@gmail.com'; 

        $clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
        $clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
        $message = trim($_POST['message']);

        $array = array();
        $array['nameMessage'] = '';
        $array['emailMessage'] = '';
        $array['messageMessage'] = '';

        if($clientName == '') {
            $array['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your name.';
        }
        if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
            $array['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
        }
        if($message == '') {
            $array['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
        }
        if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '') {
            // Send email
        $headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);    
        }

    header('Location: thanks.php');
    }        

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks but this just broke the page. Solved it though, thanks to Stijn Raeymaekers.